# mongodb remove corrupt BSON

Tags: mongodb

when doing a query on my db i get

`"$err" : "BSONElement: bad type 109", "code" : 10320 }`
In order to identify the document i traversed the complete collection with pymongo and got 

 `AssertionError: Result batch started from 0, expected 205881`

i am able to group my collection based on some field and sort by date, which reduces the search space....

I m not able to get the exact doc but at least locate it within some range...
trying to `remove` unfortunately raises:

`BSONObj size: 1597071153 (0x315F315F) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: mall.jpg: ?type=115`

Any idea how i can fix the issue... 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a replica set I'd try the same query on a secondary to see if the data is corrupted there and fail over to the secondary if it's okay.

If you are not on a replica set I'd consider restoring from a backup as this error is an indication of some corruption somewhere.

If you have no backups I'd consider dropping and recreating indexes (sometimes the corruption is in an index).

I'd also check to see what version of mongodb you are running and possibly upgrade to a recent stable release as a way to fix any known bugs.

Failing that I'd try a database repair http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/